# How to make a single line query include multiple lines in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to take a set of data and expand it by adding date rows based an existing field.  For instance, If I have the following table (`TABLE1`):

```
ID   NAME  YEAR
1    John  2001
2    Jim   2012
3    Sally 2005
```

I want to take this data and put it into another table but expand it to include a set of months (and from there I can add monthly information).  If I just look at the first record (`John`) my result would be:

```
ID   NAME  YEAR   MONTH
1   John   2001   01-JAN-2001
1   John   2001   01-FEB-2001
1   John   2001   01-MAR-2001
...
1   John   2001   01-DEC-2001
```

I have the mechanism to derive my monthly dates but how do I extract the data from `TABLE1` to make `TABLE2`.  Here is just a quick query but, of course, I get the `ORA-01427 single-row subquery returns more than one row` as expect.  Just not sure how to organize the query to put these two pieces together:

```
select id, 
   name, 
   year, 
   book_cd, 
   (SELECT  ADD_MONTHS('01-JAN-'|| year, LEVEL - 1)  
          FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12) month
from table1 ;
```

I realize I cant do this but I'm not sure how to put the two pieces together. I plan to bulk process records so it wont be one ID at a time Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cross join:

```
select t.id, 
       t.name, 
       t.year, 
       t.book_cd,
       ADD_MONTHS(to_date(t.year || '-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), m.rn) as mnth
  from table1 t
 cross join (select rownum - 1 as rn
               from dual
            connect by rownum <= 12) m
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.  I'll need to investigate this cross join functionality.  First time Ive heard of it!